# Trying to plot a graph using matplotlib and only the x-axis gets labeled and also it gets labeled with a different name that I defined in my code

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My problem is that I only can label the x-axis of my graph. Furthermore, the label is a different name than I defined it to be in the code. Also, when plotting a grid it only plots the y-axis grid and not both.

This is the code for the dataframe I want to plot

```
time_field = "thread_created_utc"
thread_field = "thread_id"

columns = [thread_field, time_field] # identify relevant columns
df_threads = df[columns].copy() # subset original dataframe to include only relevant information
df_threads[time_field] = pd.to_datetime(df_threads[time_field]) # Convert the time column to a datetime object

time_gran = "H" # time granularity: use H if hourly, D if daily

df_threads = (df_threads
              .set_index(time_field)    # set the timing as the index of the dataframe
              .resample(time_gran)      # Use resample function to group data by time (e.g., days or hours)
              [thread_field]            # specify the column we need to aggregate/count 
              .nunique()                # count the number of unique elements within each group
             )
df_threads
```

```
#Plotting time series, defining what kind of graph, x and y axis labeling, the title, the size #of the graph, the width of the line and colour
df_threads.plot(kind = "line", x = "Time in hours", y = "Number of movies", title = "Number of movies per hour", figsize= (10, 5), linewidth = 1.5, color = "orange")

#Displaying a grid which makes it easier to read the values.
plt.grid(axis = "both", color = "grey", linestyle = "--", linewidth = 0.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3YwD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not having a sample of you data makes it hard to troubleshoot, but here is an example of what you ought to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(1)
timestamps = pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=24, freq="H")
thread_ids = np.random.randint(1, 6, size=len(timestamps))
df = pd.DataFrame({"thread_created_utc": timestamps, "thread_id": thread_ids})


time_field = "thread_created_utc"
thread_field = "thread_id"

columns = [thread_field, time_field] # identify relevant columns
df_threads = df[columns].copy() # subset original dataframe to include only relevant information
df_threads[time_field] = pd.to_datetime(df_threads[time_field]) # Convert the time column to a datetime object

time_gran = "H" # time granularity: use H if hourly, D if daily

df_threads = (df_threads
              .set_index(time_field)    # set the timing as the index of the dataframe
              .resample(time_gran)      # Use resample function to group data by time (e.g., days or hours)
              [thread_field]            # specify the column we need to aggregate/count 
              .nunique()                # count the number of unique elements within each group
             )

df_threads.plot(kind="line", title="Number of threads per hour", figsize=(10, 5), linewidth=1.5, color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Number of threads")
plt.grid(color="grey", linestyle="--", linewidth=0.5)
```

[image]